# Regex asterisk usage

Tags: javascript, regex

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
 `x* : *Matches the preceding item x 0 or more times.*`

Essentially the preceding characters should be completely optional. The string will be matched whether they exist or not. So why is it that:

**1.**

```
var text  = "foobar";
var re    = /q*/;
var found = text.match(re);
console.log(found); // prints '["", index: 0, input: "foobar"]'
```

but

```
var re    = /qz*/;
console.log(found); // prints 'null'
```

Both expressions equally don't exist and thus should be matched 0 times and '""' should be returned.

Or:

**2.**

```
var re    = /fz*/;
console.log(found); // prints '["f", index: 0, input: "foobar"]'
```

but

```
var re    = /fzq*/;
console.log(found); // prints 'null'
```

What's happening here? From my understanding `'fzq'` doesn't exist so should be matched 0 times, and '""' should be returned, right? And if it somehow matches on per character basis instead of the whole string, `'fzq*'` should return the same result as `'fz'` - `'f'` is matched once and the rest is matched 0 times. But apparently this is not what's happening.

Could someone shed some light on what the hell is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> x* : *Matches the preceding item x 0 or more times.*

You misunderstood this statement with *everything* before `*` is matched zero or more times.

When you match `q*`, the regex will search for `q` in the input string. As there is no `q` in the `foobar`, it'll return an empty string.

When you try to match `qz*`, the regex will try to search for **any number of `z`s after `q`**. As there is no `q` in the input string, it'll return `null`.

To match more characters by `*` or any other quantifiers, you need to group them using parenthesis.

```
(qz)*
```

which means, match the string `qz` zero or more times.

To understand a regex, you can use https://regex101.com/ site.